# Azure AD SSO, login.live not found

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, openid

I using aws serverless architecture with cognito. I need to implement azure active directory. I have managed to setup all configuration to connect my azure AD account with aws cognito using OpenId.
So when I try to login with Azure AD, it show me login page with only email address field. When I add email address and click next, it show me this error login.live not found.
I can bypass this, only if i login to my azure active directory account first and then goto my app and click SSO azure AD, it wont show my login page but automatically logged the user in.

So can anyone help me on this, how to resolve this problem, user should login with AD without first login with azure account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create or edit your sign-in/sign-up flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

If you haven't added an external identity provider it won't recognize the email. Or you need to sign up first using the user flow.

Comment: thankyou for your reply, but this isn't the problem. like I said, if I already loggedin in azure portal and then try to login with sso in my application it work fine.

Secondly if I add business email instead of personal one, then this error not appear. So I think it is something to do with personal emails.